# Which suppressed/silenced weapons don't make you appear on minimap?

Tags: battlefield-3

In BF3 each time you shoot, you automatically appear on enemy's minimap. However with silenced weapons (eg. pistols) you don't. Things are less clear how it works with other suppressed (SMGs, carabines, LMGs, rifles). There have been reports that with some you do, some you don't. So which do, which don't?

I'm interested how the situation is right now (post 24-November patch) or even better how it will look after next week's patch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not *supposed* to show up on the minimap at all with any silenced weapon. (Not flash suppressors, silencers).

That is not currently the case, it is a bit random depending on which gun you're referring to. This is confirmed as a bug by DICE, and I believe the upcoming Dec 6 patch fixes this, so for the purposes of this answer, let's just go with *any silencer should ensure that you don't show up on the minimap when firing.*

> Fixed several weapons so they are properly suppressed and hide the player on the minimap when fired.

http://www.bluesnews.com/s/128125/battlefield-3-patch-this-week